# object created for a linear layout inside a fragment returns null value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create object for a linear layout already present inside fragment xml file, the xml file is as below file name is detailfragment.xml,

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:id="@+id/detailBaseLayout"
         > </LinearLayout>
```

and my class file DetailFragment.java is as below,

```
         public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment,container, false);
                 return view;
              }

              public void setText(String item) {

                  Log.w("DetailFragment", "DetailFragment"+item);

                  LinearLayout Blayout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailBaseLayout);
                  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity()); 
                  layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                  Log.w("Entering into common code","Entering into common code="+item);
                  TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                  tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                  tv.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
                  tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT,10);
                  tv.setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0);
                  tv.setText(item);
                  layout.addView(tv);
                  if(Blayout == null) {

                      Log.w("Linear Layout is null","Linear Layout is null"+Blayout); 

                  }
                  Blayout.addView(layout);
             }
       }
```

When running the above code I am getting Linear Layout is null (Hence a null pointer exception saying error at DetailFragment.setText and so on) ,even though I have given the id correctly and used getView() to get the inflated fragments view.Also, I am getting "item" value correctly no problem with that.
Here is my MainActivity code where i am calling setText,

```
       public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener{


           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              new MyDBHelper(this);

           }

           // if the wizard generated an onCreateOptionsMenu you can delete
           // it, not needed for this tutorial

           @Override
           public void onQuestionClicked(String item,ArrayList<AnswerOptions> Answers) {
               Log.d("onRssItemSelected", "onRssItemSelected"+link);
               DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.detail_fragment);
               if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {

                   Log.d("fragmentisnlayout", "fragmentisnlayout"+fragment.isInLayout());
                   fragment.setText(item);
                   for(int i=0;i<Answers.size();i++) {

                      Log.d("onQClick", "onQClick"+Answers.get(i).getAnswerText());
                      fragment.setRadioButton(i,Answers.get(i).getAnswerText());

                   }

               } 
               Log.d("onRssItemSelected", "onRssItemSelected"+fragment);
           }

     }
```

Comment: when was setText used?

Comment: I think that wont matter, my main issue is when I simply create an object for the linear layout present in xml file  and check the objects value it is null, any clues why?

Comment: yes it does matter you might used it before you inflate the view.

Comment: oh, you are right please find the detail of where i am calling setText in the comment i have given for answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where and when was setText called? The problem must be fired at getView().

Use setText in onViewCreated(View _view, Bundle _savedInstanceState) and better to replace getView() with _view.

Try this dummy code:

Added newInstance to DetailFragment:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(Context cxt, String item) {
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("data", item);
   return Fragment.instantiate(...., args);
}


onViewCreated(....) {
     setText(getArguments().getString("data"));
}
```

also, your detailfragment.xml has a problem, according to your code, your linearlayout tried to find itself. I gave a suggestion to change your xml.

```
<Framelayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/detailBaseLayout" 
> </LinearLayout> 
</Framelayout>
```

Comment: I am calling setText on the implementation of interface onQuestionClicked(of Listfragment - another fragment) created in mainActivity , after creating object for DetailFragment using fragmentmanager as fr and fr.setText(item).

Comment: any idea on how to call setText inside onViewCreated ?

Comment: It could be the problem that you passed data to DetailFragment before DetailFragment has finished building its whole view, this cases getView() with a NULL.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I searched web for  how to pass values to newInstance of DetailFragment from inside the interface implementation of listfragment in mainactivity, but was unsuccessful, need your help.if you require Mainactivity code I will edit my question adding that code. Thanks again.

Comment: Give more details about your question is better, something like MainActivity etc.

Comment: where have you initialized your DetailsFragment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57915/discussion-between-echo-learner-php-and-teetracker).